# usage of the verb to bridge in "Bridging someone to something"

Tags: expressions, word-usage, british-english, gerunds

My friend suggested a tag line for our project: "Bridging you to your dream higher education online" and I have doubts that "bridging you to smth." is a proper word usage.

I've never heard this expression before. I've only heard "Bridging the gap between smth and smth" and "bridge between dreaming and living your dreams".

The meaning behind this is "moving you towards your dream", building a "connection, bridge" leading students to their dream university.

What do you think? 
You help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I agree with you, it's strange. A bridge connects two things so that *other* things can cross over between them. If a bridge connects "you" to something else, if *you* cross over the bridge, what is the bridge connecting? :)

Answer (score 3):

The construction of bridging A to B sounds, looks and feels weird.

Although it is clear what the tag-line is supposed to mean, it does not seem to convey its message in a natural way.

As [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164409/usage-of-the-verb-to-bridge-in-bridging-someone-to-something#comment342642_164410) mentioned, the usage of bridge may be creeping, mirroring verbs like connect and join, but I have not seen it used in that way. (And I happen to work in IT - if that counts for anything :P ).

I would suggest to substitute a more appropriate verb in the tag line; depending on the exact message you want to convey you could focus on the connection (connect, link, join) or on the movement of the student *towards* the university of choice or the realization of their dream. *Realizing your dream higher education* would be an interesting grammar-twist...)

Answer (score 0):

*to bridge: *vb (tr)

1. to connect or reduce the distance between: let us bridge our differences.

Source: Collins Dictionary

Yes it is correct and very effective in the idea it conveys.

Comment: I don't see how the example Collins gives matches their definition, and, like OP, I haven't seen one that does. The example certainly does not license OP's queried **bridge X to Y** usage. Surely it's a shorter version of 'bridge over our differences' (cf 'patch over our differences') and an idiosyncratic, idiomatic usage. Although the usage OP queries _may_ be creeping in (mirroring connect / join / attach / stick / glue ... A to B), probably in the computer domain, the direct object of 'bridge' is traditionally a noun phrase referencing the 'gap', whether geographical or metaphorical.

Comment: That is a very  interesting point on the usage of "bridge" . So  you think that the sentence in question is unacceptable?

Comment: Unacceptable? Who decides? But for me, it's a bridge usage too far.